# Resampling using pyresample grid definition

Tags: python, coordinate-system, resampling

I would like to resample a dataset to another projection and scale. Following the documentation in pyresample website [here](https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grid.html). We need to have an Area Definition, which is tedious to do.

```
import numpy as np
from pyresample import image, geometry
area_def = geometry.AreaDefinition('areaD', 'Europe (3km, HRV, VTC)', 'areaD',
                               {'a': '6378144.0', 'b': '6356759.0',
                                'lat_0': '50.00', 'lat_ts': '50.00',
                                'lon_0': '8.00', 'proj': 'stere'},
                               800, 800,
                               [-1370912.72, -909968.64,
                                1029087.28, 1490031.36])
msg_area = geometry.AreaDefinition('msg_full', 'Full globe MSG image 0 degrees',
                               'msg_full',
                               {'a': '6378169.0', 'b': '6356584.0',
                                'h': '35785831.0', 'lon_0': '0',
                                'proj': 'geos'},
                               3712, 3712,
                               [-5568742.4, -5568742.4,
                                5568742.4, 5568742.4])
data = np.ones((3712, 3712))
msg_con_quick = image.ImageContainerQuick(data, msg_area)
area_con_quick = msg_con_quick.resample(area_def)
result_data_quick = area_con_quick.image_data
msg_con_nn = image.ImageContainerNearest(data, msg_area, radius_of_influence=50000)
area_con_nn = msg_con_nn.resample(area_def)
result_data_nn = area_con_nn.image_data
```

In my case, I already have arrays that represent the latitudes and longitudes and would like to use them for the purpose of resampling. Pyresample [mention](https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geo_def.html): "If the longitude and latitude values for an area are known, the complexity of an AreaDefinition can be skipped by using a GridDefinition object instead."
So I create the grid definition using:

```
import numpy as np
from pyresample.geometry import GridDefinition
lons = np.ones((100, 100))
lats = np.ones((100, 100))
grid_def = GridDefinition(lons=lons, lats=lats)
```

However, when I try using Grid Definitions:

```
from pyresample.geometry import GridDefinition
grid_def_x = GridDefinition(lons=lons_x, lats=lats_x)
grid_def_y = GridDefinition(lons=lons_y, lats=lats_y)
msg_con_quick = image.ImageContainerQuick(data_x, grid_def_x)
area_con_quick = msg_con_quick.resample(grid_def_y)
result_data_quick = area_con_quick.image_data
```

I get:
TypeError: area_def must be of type geometry.AreaDefinition.

Is there a way to convert GridDefinition to AreaDefinition? or any other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Resampling is done using the following line

```
from pyresample.kd_tree import resample_nearest
result = resample_nearest(grid_def, data, area_def, radius_of_influence=20000, fill_value=None)
```